# C: Trying to print an error from a function

Tags: c, function, printf

I'm creating a function that gets the intercept from two line inputs and displays it as a point. It works most of the time, but when there is no intersection (lines are parallel), I (-inf, -inf). I'm trying to get the function to instead print an "ERROR." Here's what I tried, but it's still returning the same thing.

```
Point getIntercept (Line a, Line b) {
    Point intercept;    
    if (a.m == b.m) {
        printf("Error");
    } else {
        double x = (a.b - b.b) / (b.m - a.m); //solves for x
        double y = a.m * x + a.b; //plugs in for y
        intercept.x = x;
        intercept.y = y;
        return intercept;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what does the function `return` after you printed `Error`?

Comment: I am wondering also if the output is line-buffered and because you do not write a newline maybe you are not (yet) seeing the `Error` that is printed. In any case you certainly need a proper return value in this case, as mentioned above.

Comment: @KamilCuk it prints the same thing it did without the if statement, meaning it prints an intercept if there is one and (-inf, -inf) if there isnt

Comment: @BepisKid What you are seeing is undefined behaviour if there is none. Do not rely on it. If you switch on compiler warnings you will probably see something like "control reaches end of non-void function". Decide on a return value to use when there is no intercept, and return it (and then test for it in the caller).

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong. If you want to know if the lines are parallel, test `a.m == b.m`, and do so __before__ doing a division by zero in the second line of your function!

Comment: I tried changing the algorithm, but it's returning the same thing, unless I set a value to intercept, but either way, error doesnt get printed

Comment: When `a.m == b.m` is true, then where is the `return` statement that returns data from your function?

Comment: You are trying to write a function that can return either a `Point` or an error. The return type clearly covers _only_ the first scenario. That's not good. I would recommend separating the two responsibilities: one function to check whether or not the lines are parallel, another function (only to be called if _not_ parallel) to calculate the intersection.

Comment: @BepisKid Please note you are _not_ improving an open question by fixing bugs that contributed to the problem. The original observation `(-inf, -inf)` no longer applies after your edit, making the question useless to others. Stackoverflow is a Q&A site; collaborative bugfixing would be better at home at GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer without comments or details:

```
Point getIntercept(Line a, Line b)
{
  Point interception;
  if (a.m != b.m) {
    interception.x = fabs(b.b - a.b) / fabs(b.m - a.m);
    interception.y = a.m * interception.x + a.b;
  }
  return interception;
}
```

You could implement an error check like this:

```
int intersect (Line a, Line b)
{
    return a.m != b.m || a.b == b.b;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
if (intersect (a, b)) {
  Point iab = getIntercept(a, b);
  printf("interception at: %f %f\n", iab.x, iab.y);
} else {
  puts ("line a, b don't intersect");
}
```

Longer answer with comments and details:

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
 
typedef struct Point
{
  double x;
  double y;
} Point;
 
typedef struct Line
{
  double m;
  double b;
} Line;
 
Point getIntercept(Line a, Line b)
{
  Point interception;
  if (a.m != b.m) {
    interception.x = fabs(b.b - a.b) / fabs(b.m - a.m);
    interception.y = a.m * interception.x + a.b;
  }
  return interception;
}
 
int intersect (Line a, Line b)
{
    return a.m != b.m || a.b == b.b;
}
 
int main ()
{
  Line a = {0.75, 0}; // a: y = 0.75x + 0
  Line b = {-0.5, 2}; // b: y = -0.5x + 2
  Line c = {0.75, 2}; // c: y = 0.75x + 2 => paralell to a
 
  if (intersect (a, b)) {
    Point iab = getIntercept(a, b);
    printf("interception at: %f %f\n", iab.x, iab.y);
  } else {
    puts ("line a, b don't intersect");
  }
  
  if (intersect (a, c)) {
    Point iac = getIntercept(a, c);
    printf("interception at: %f %f\n", iac.x, iac.y);
  } else {
    puts ("line a, c don't intersect");
  }
}
```

Result (outputs generated from long answer snippet):

```
interception at: 1.600000 1.200000                                                                                                                                       
line a, c don't intersect
```

[image: interception-result]

As other users have already stated: Either throw an error or return something useful in this case.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the feedback. Yeah, I just have the code from an online-compiler. I can edit that. But when I do return the struct Point can I check for NULL as in:
`if (result == NULL)`? I think it has to be a pointer - no?

Comment: So basically `if (a.m == c.m && a.b != c.b)` the lines never intersect. You can write that as a quick function that takes two `Line` as arguments, e.g. `int intersect (Line a, Line b) { return a.m != b.m || a.b == b.b; }` See [Line Intercept 2](https://paste.opensuse.org/58868697)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have implemented your change requests. And thanks for the helpful hints. I am quite new to C/C++ myself - I normally develop in Java.

Comment: Your changes are fine -- Since `Point` cannot return information indicating whether the lines intersect, if I were writing it, I'd probably pass the `Point` to be filled as a parameter and have the function return `1/0` to indicate `success/failure` - or something similar to: [Line Intercept 3](https://paste.opensuse.org/24865490). Here all parameters are pointers (they are smaller to pass than the `Point` or `Line` itself) and it allows you to operate on that memory address and make changes within the function. If you just pass `Point` by-value -- any changes would be lost `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I totally get this. Ah so this is similar to PHP where you can pass params by reference with &var. I am so used to it in Java you always call functions by reference with objects only if you have primitives. But structs are not classes in c so yeah. It is fun to see how this is all connected and the concepts of C are alot closer to machine code level. Is there a reason to return int over bool? more states?

Comment: Yes, but think of it this way -- C has only *pass-by-value*, no references. If you use `Line a` as a parameter, the function receives a copy in `a` an it is no different than if you had declared `Line a` within the function. However if you pass the address to the struct by-value, the function receives a copy of the pointer, but the pointer contains the same address as the original. So if you operate on that memory address within the function, you are operating on the same memory location as the original and changes are not lost. So passing an address by value is how C manages a reference.

Comment: You can make it `bool`, but you need to include `stdbool.h` to do so. Using a `int` is just as easy. You evaluate either `0` (`false`) or anything not zero (`true`) is how it works. You can write a function so that either `0` or `1` (anything not `0`) is either `false/true` or `true/false` -- it is up to you. The logical not `!` is an easy way to handle the negative of each case.